# React Native Error: TypeError: null is not an object _RNGestureHandlerModule.default.Direction

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have tried many ways to fix this error but all attempts have failed.

> - FOR ANDROID NOT IOS.

[_RNGestureHandlerModule.default.Direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVPad.png)

I was trying for android. I found bug **react-native-gesture-handler** buy I don't know how to fix it.

I am following this instruction  step by step https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

I tried linking the react-native-gesture-handler manual. and also tried unlinked. 
I made **react-native.config.js** with code

```
exports = {
    dependencies: {
      'react-native-gesture-handler': {
        platforms: {
          android: null,
          ios: null,
        },
      },
    },
  };
```

I am using System:

```
 OS: Linux 5.3 Arch Linux undefined
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700K CPU @ 3.70GHz
    Memory: 16.06 GB / 31.21 GB
    Shell: 5.0.11 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.13.0 - /usr/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.19.1 - /usr/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.12.1 - /usr/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
    react-native: 0.61.4 => 0.61.4 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1

"react-navigation": "^2.18.2",
"react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3"
```

> - FOR ANDROID NOT IOS.

[_RNGestureHandlerModule.default.Direction I wrote about the bug react-native-gesture-handler Github](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/835)

Comment: Did you tried 'react-native link react-native-gesture-handler' after installing react-native-gesture-handler

Comment: is different  after install or before installl ? I tried link when installed gesture-handler

Comment: Have you added the following in MainActivity ? :
```
@Override
protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
@Override
protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
}
};
}
```

Comment: yeah I tried it, but it's not worked

Answer (score 0):

Just simply you should comment line :
// export { default as Directions } from './Directions';

in the your project -> node_modules -> react-native-gesture-handler -> GestureHandler.js

I think it hope help you

Answer (score 0):

Please try with

> `Pod update`

It's working for me